# Recycler View Does not works in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have been making an app that uses a `recyclerView` in a `Fragment` but the contents of the `recyclerView` have not been showing up. It shows:

```
 'No adapter attached; skipping layout'.
```

Featured Helper Class:

```
public class FeaturedHelperClass {

    int image;
    String title;

    public FeaturedHelperClass(int image, String title) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        featuredRecycle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false).findViewById(R.id.explore_recycle);
        recycle();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    }

private void recycle(){

        featuredRecycle.setHasFixedSize(true);
        featuredRecycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        ArrayList<FeaturedHelperClass> featuredLocations = new ArrayList<>();

        featuredLocations.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.mcdonald, "Mcdonald's"));
        featuredLocations.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.kfc, "KFC"));
        featuredLocations.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.starbucks, "Starbucks"));

        adapter = new FeaturedAdapter(featuredLocations);
        featuredRecycle.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Your given data and codes are not enough. post your fragment_dashboard.xml. and explain why do your inflate featuredRecycle and your fragment separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inflation logic seems to be flawed, Try changing the following in your `onCreateView`

```
featuredRecycle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false).findViewById(R.id.explore_recycle);
recycle();
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
```

into

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
featuredRecycle = view.findViewById(R.id.explore_recycle);
recycle();
return view;
```

Answer (score 1):

The below will work for you, but it is not a good approach to delay the inflation of view in the fragment. Since you are doing some tasks before returning the view, it delays view inflation.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
         featuredRecycle = view.findViewById(R.id.explore_recycle);
         recycle()
         return view;
   }
```

Doing the following would be an optimal approach,

```
//inflate the view and return
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
         return view;
   }

//this callback is just after the view inflation, you set your ui here
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             featuredRecycle = view.findViewById(R.id.explore_recycle);
             recycle()
   }
```

Comment: instead of getView(), we can use the view itself. basically, both will give the inflated view only.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the `'No adapter attached; skipping layout'.` after the view inflation recycler view adapter is not attached.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        featuredRecycle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false).findViewById(R.id.explore_recycle);
        recycle();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    }
```

because recycle() method will be executed before the inflation of the view.

we can change this into

```
//inflate the view and return
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
         return view;
   }

//this callback is just after once the view get inflated in the screen
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             featuredRecycle = view.findViewById(R.id.explore_recycle);
             recycle();
   }
```

now we get the `featuredRecycle` view and recycle() logic will be executed recycler will be drawn.